# How to Parse JSON Arrays to SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm looking to create a table of data (see "Output Table") from the below JSON. I can't seem to get to the "final mile". Can someone show me the way to properly handle the parsing of the arrays into the desired output table?

Thanks! Russ

Desired Output Table
[image]

Output I am getting
[image]

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =
'{
    "totalCount": 1,
    "nextPageKey": null,
    "result": [
      {
        "metricId": "builtin:host.cpu.usage",
        "data": [
            {
              "dimensions": [
                "HOST-CCCC3F95D7CE56"
              ],
              "dimensionMap": {
                "dt.entity.host": "HOST-CCCC3F95D7CE56"
              },
              "timestamps": [
                1612634400000,
                1612645200000,
                1612656000000

               ],
               "values": [
                0.37900028935185187,
                0.3709309895833333,
                0.5088975694444444

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}'

Select TableA.totalCount, TableResult.metricId,
TableDim.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH(
        totalCount  int,
        result      NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    ) as TableA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TableA.result)
    WITH(
        metricId    VARCHAR(100),
        data        NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    )TableResult
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TableResult.data)
    WITH(
        dimensions  NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON,
        timestamps  NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON,
        [values]    NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    )TableDim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what the correlation is between `timestamps` and `values`, but I've assumed it's by array index.

Is `dimensions` always a single value in the array? I have assumed so.

You then need to use `OPENJSON` (and no `WITH` block) to break out the two arrays, and join them together on index, [which is supplied in `key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value):

```sql
Select TableA.totalCount, TableResult.metricId,
TableDim.dimensions, Vals.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH(
        totalCount  int,
        result      NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    ) as TableA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TableA.result)
    WITH(
        metricId    VARCHAR(100),
        data        NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    )TableResult
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TableResult.data)
    WITH(
        dimensions  NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.dimensions[0]',
        timestamps  NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON,
        [values]    NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
    )TableDim
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT tm.value AS Timestamp, v.value AS Value
    FROM OPENJSON(TableDim.timestamps) tm
    JOIN OPENJSON(TableDim.[values]) v ON v.[key] = tm.[key]
) Vals
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. Regarding your question asking about whether or not "dimensions" is always a single value, the answer would be; not necessarily so. In the case where it was not so, how would that change the structure of the solution?